# “einmal in der Woche” vs. “einmal die Woche”

Tags: difference, time

Is there a difference between the following?

> einmal in der Woche
>   einmal die Woche

[Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/#auto/de/once%20in%20a%20week) suggests the first one, yet I wonder if the second can be used synonymously.

Comment: In English both variants are fine: "once in a week", "once a week". In German either. Additionally, "einmal pro Woche" is fine as well. – None is "better". Voted for close as opinion-based.

Comment: Depending on the context "jede Woche" or "wöchentlich" may be fine as well, but the given three variants are nearer to your phrase and are all fine.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no difference and you can choose between the two phrases. There is also a third possibility that has the same meaning:

> einmal *pro* Woche

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility is

> wöchentlich

which also means that something happens once a week.

Answer (score 2):

There is a difference between the two phrases: They do mean exactly the same (once a week), but

> einmal die Woche

is only colloquial and I wouldn't use this in written German.